# When will $ax+1$ be divisible by $b$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Consider two natural numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $b$ is prime and $a$ is indivisible by $b$.
Then, for which integral values of $x$ should $ax+1$ be divisible by $b$ ?
I tried different values of $a$ and $b$ and found the values of $x$ satisfing the above condition in each case, but saw no pattern.
Please give me the answer of this question with proper explanation if possible because I am trying to prove something and this is a crucial part of that proof.

Comment: I believe you want to try Bezout's lemma.

Comment: May be, but I don't know Bezout's lemma clearly.

Comment: Basically it says that for nonzero integers $a,b$, if $\gcd(a,b) = d$, then there exists integers $x_1,x_2$ so that $ax_1+bx_2 = d$. In the case you have that $\gcd(a,b) = 1$. You should see the result.

Comment: Good explanation of Bezout's Lemma but please explain me what do you mean by "You should see the result." ?

Comment: Suppose $\gcd(a,b) = 1$. by Bezout's lemma, there exists $x_1,x_2$ (integers) so that $ax_1+bx_2 = 1$. This is equivalent to $bx_2 = 1 - ax_1$. Equivalently, $bx_2 = a(-x_1)+1$. By definition of divisibility, $b$ divides $a(-x_1)+1$.

Comment: Thanks, but how should I find the values of $x_1$ and $x_2$ ?

Comment: Using the euclidean algorithm. You can check the wiki for that information. It should do a great job in explaining it.

Comment: @ShubhamAvasthi are you given that $gcd(a,b) = 1$ ??

Comment: Yes, Mr. alkabary, $gcd(a,b)=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer using Fermat's Little Theorem. 
The answer should be $x=b*n-a^{b-2}$ where $n$ is an integer.

Comment: You mean Fermat's Little Theorem, the last theorem is very different.

Comment: Yes, I have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

We wish to solve $ax\equiv -1 \pmod b$ for $x$ with $a$ and $b$ given and coprime, and $b$ prime. This is simply the negative of the multiplicative inverse of $a$ in $\mathbb Z_b$, which can be computed by a variety of methods for any given $a$ and $b$, since $a$ and $b$ are coprime. Once this value, let us say $-a^{-1}$, is found, the integral solutions for $x$ are $x\equiv -a^{-1} \pmod b$, or $x=-a^{-1}+bn$ for any integer $n$.

Comment: What do you mean by ≡ and  Zb ?

Comment: How can $-a^{-1} + bn$ be a natural number when a is not equal to 1 ?

Comment: @ShubhamAvasthi, if you haven't learned congruences, don't worry about the answer. It's just another way to realize the answer.

Comment: Yes, I don't know congruences.Maybe that is why I am not able to understand this answer. Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: You can learn [congruences here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html).

Comment: $x \equiv y \pmod p$ means that $x$ and $y$ are congruent modulo $p$; that is, when divided by $p$ the remainder is the same. $\mathbb Z_b$ in practice means, here, the integers from $0$ to $b$ (more properly it is a complete residue system modulo $b$).

Comment: How can $−a^{-1}+bn$ be a natural number when a is not equal to 1 ?

Comment: @ShubhamAvasthi $a^{-1}$ does not denote the "normal" multiplicative inverse of $a$, that is $\frac 1a$, but the multiplicative inverse of $a$ in $\mathbb Z_b$, that is, the number by which we must multiply $a$ in order to obtain something which is congruent to $1$ modulo $b$. For instance, modulo $5$ the multiplicative inverse of $3$ is $2$, since $2\cdot 3\equiv 1 \pmod 5$.